# How can I switch the power on/off to cut BIG currents (200A)?

Tags: relay, switch

Context: I have an off-grid cabin with PV powered 12V DC. I want to cut power to an inverter (12V DC ->220V AC) when I leave by pressing a button as it draws too much in standby.

Most relays I have seen that can be connected to the Arduino typically handle 10A. My inverter draws up to 180A@12V at full power (2000 W), which is way more than anything I have seen. How can I control the power to this inverter?

Someone told me of hacks that utilize the fact that you get manual switches/relays that handle big current, so you can use the Arduino to control a motor pressing the physical switch, but the concept seems somewhat brittle ... Any other takes?

```
            ┌────────────┐
            │  PV array  │
            └──────┬─────┘
                   │
             ┌─────┴───┐
             │ Charger │
           ┌─┴─────────┘
           │
           │
  ┌────────┴──┐         ┌─────────┐
  │ Batteries ├─────────┤Inverter ├────────────┐
  └────────┬──┘         └─────────┘            │
           │                                   │
           │                          ┌────────┴─────┐
           │                          │220V circuit  │
       ┌───┴───────────────┐          │  w/appliances│
Has    │ Fuse box          │          └──────────────┘
on/off │ / 12v distribution│
switch!└───────────────────┘


        ┌──────────────┐
        │12V appliances│
        └──────────────┘
```

Comment: What is the model number of the inverter?

Comment: I do not have it readily available (it's a 4 hour drive), but it is one of the many generic China versions readily available on BangGood. Paid like 200$ for the 2KW peak/1KW continuous version.

Comment: There may be better ways to go about it involving an Arduino, but they will largely be dependent on the capabilities of the device. The typical way inverters themselves solve the cost of standby is by offering a way to probe for a load a regular intervals sometimes called "search". But there's nothing really Arduino related about that aspect of it.

Comment: The motorized manual switch idea is good because it uses (builds upon) rated components, so your insurance won't deny a claim if the cabin burns down due to electrical problems stemming from ali express junk. If you want to do it "right", use a suitably rated contactor, not a relay. Or use a manual switch; they aren't any harder to use than a button.

Comment: @dandavis Of course there exists ali express junk for this, but if you use a properly rated relay or electric switch for automotive applications, these should conform to local regulations as well. Of course, they won't be in the $5 range.

Comment: I don't know the exact physical setup, but a manual switch is probably problematic due to the location of the different components. The wires between the battery and the inverter should be as short as possible, to avoid energy loss. A cable for 180A @ 12V is  very thick. So depending on the layout, it's not possible to install a mechanical switch in a convenient place without adding a lot of extra cable length.

Comment: That's exactly it. Cable length issue, Hence the need to disable it using another remote mechanism. Also, I cannot fit search lying on the inside of my walls

Comment: @PMF good point about placement, strike my manual switch suggestion. I still worry that automotive starter relays aren't designed to handle long-term current, whereas contactors/solenoids are. I doubt the price differential is enough to justify the risk in a high-stakes situation.

Comment: @dandavis Yea, I'll clarify that in my answer. Of course it's important to read the specs regarding long-term currents. The main point actually is that there are 12 V relays or solenoids for high currents, but none (or few?) that operate on 5V directly.

Comment: @PMF sorry to be a nit, but this is a possibly life safety or mega buck problem; i want fellow makers to be safe. Might mention that many starter relays consume dozens of watts too, a consideration for solar. A latching contactor is zero rest current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look for something like a "starter relay" for an engine. Those switch on 12 V and can handle currents of 150A and more. I've seen various models on the site of my favorite distributor.

**Check the data sheet to make sure the relay can handle a continuous current of 180A**, as many starter relays can only handle the current for short periods of time (you're not running the starter motor of an engine for more than a few seconds). Other possible types are 12V-industry-rated high-current relays. Also mentioned in a comment above: The hold-current of the relay shouldn't be to big, so you don't waste energy just for the switch.

You might need to use a 2-step solution, to first convert the 5V output of the Arduino to 12 V to control the relay. (use a small relay for this, or just a mosfet).